# Async Task progress bar in for loop

Tags: java, android

-I have tried to hit web service using Async Task method.

-Here the for loop will dismiss the progress dialog from the first and crashes the Application. Kindly check this code and give suggestions.

**Code**

```
for(Pageview pg:views)
{
 value1=url1+"userid="+pg.getuserid()+"&chapterid="+pg.getchapterid()+"&pageno="+pg.getpageno()+"&view%20time="+pg.getviewtime()+"&IMEI%20no="+pg.getimeino()+"&feedback="+pg.getfeedback()+"&Comments="+pg.getcomments();
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 System.out.println(value1);
// feedbackdata feedback1=new feedbackdata();
 feedbak.execute(value1);
    feedbackdata.loadingProgress = GUIStaticMethod.returnProgressBar(getApplicationContext());

        //myLoginDataFatcher.start();

GUIStaticMethod.mProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {



        if(res1.contains("Page View Insertion Successfully")==true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if(res1.contains("Page View Insertion Failed")==true)
        {

        }
    }


 });
```

**ERROR**

```
04-02 10:52:34.956: E/AndroidRuntime(234): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:383)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at com.example.wireframe.webviewurl$11.onDismiss(webviewurl.java:1751)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1058)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-02 10:52:34.976: E/AndroidRuntime(234):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Lucifer You edited the post, why did you not supply an indentation which improves readability?

Comment: From the stacktrace I see that AsyncTask is being executed in `onDismiss(...)` method, but I can't see it in your code.

Comment: @ClassStacker, Status Completed :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `AsyncTask` instance for every iteration.

```
new AsyncTask().execute(value);
```

The reason being that you cannot execute a thread again, because once the thread is done with the `run()` method, you cannot restart it. And that's why when you try to restart it, it gives you the `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute same AsyncTask multiple time as exception suggested. Initialize feedback object under the for loop and then execute

According to AsyncTask Threading rules

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

Answer (score 0):

It says: `Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)`. That is, you create an AsyncTask, execute it *once*, and let it be garbage-collected. You cannot call `execute()` more than once for the same instance.